# Performing a conditional join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database. My database has two tables:

```
Customer             Order
--------             -----
ID (int)             ID (int)
Name                 CustomerID (int)
EmailAddress
```

When I query these tables, I might have a orderID. If I have an order ID, I want to return the customer associated with it. If I do NOT have an order ID, or if it equals 0, I want to return all of the customers. In an attempt to do this, I've written the following query:

```
SELECT 
  o.[ID]
FROM
  [Order] o
WHERE 
  o.[ID]=@orderID
```

This query returns all orders with OrderID. However, I'm not sure how to do my conditional query. Is that even possible in SQL Server? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want you could use a `case` statement with Conduit's answer. Basically

```
CASE
  WHEN @orderid = 0 OR @orderid IS NULL
    SELECT * from Customer
  ELSE
    select c.*
    from Customer c
      inner join order o
        on c.ID = o.CustomerID
    where o.orderID = @orderID
END;
```

It may not be exact, I am not on a box with Sql Server installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [**COALESCE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190349.aspx) in sql server -

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c
WHERE c.Id IN (
        SELECT o.[CustomerID]
        FROM [Order] o
        WHERE o.[ID] = COALESCE(@orderID, o.[ID])
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerID = coalsece( (select TOP 1 customerID from Orders WHERE OrderId= @OrderID), CustomerID)
```

.

```
With CustomerOrders As (
     SELECT CustomerID, ID as OrderID
     FROM Orders
     WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerOrders co ON c.ID = coalesce(co.CustomerID, c.ID)
```